# How to pass jQuery variable from slider to url to PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, hash, anchor

I am a beginner. I am using the [Filament Groups jQuery UI slider](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_jquery_ui_slider_from_a_select_element_now_with_aria_support/). I made two sliders and want to use the two corresponding variables in my PHP scripts. 
I want to pass the jQuery variables to my current url (http://url.com) to the new url (http://url.com/#slide1=7&slide2=6) and read the url variables off into PHP variables ($var1=7, $var2=6).

How would I create an anchor tag (#) for my jQuery variables?

How can I pass the values to the url?

How can I read the variables in the url to PHP variables?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        //demo 1
        var num_var = $('select#num').selectToUISlider({labels:7}).next();
        var allpha_var = $('select#allpha').selectToUISlider({labels:7}).next();    

        //demo 2
        $('select#valueA, select#valueB').selectToUISlider();

        //demo 3
        $('select#valueAA, select#valueBB').selectToUISlider({
            labels: 12
        });

        //fix color 
        fixToolTipColor();
    });
```

HTML

```
<form action="#">
    <!-- demo 1 -->
    <fieldset>

        <select name="num" id="num">
        <optgroup label="low">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="mid">
            <option value="3" >3</option>
            <option value="4" selected="selected">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="high">
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
        </optgroup>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
```

The finished product is similar to [Example of what I want](http://www.yummly.com/search#flavor.salty.max=0.6666666666666666&flavor.salty.min=0&q=cookie&start=0)

Comment: Ever heard of ajax? I believe that is what you need

Comment: you may use ajax functions from jquery like post or get depending on your needs

Comment: Ajax, heard it mentioned. Okay thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have to get the data into PHP, you have to pass them this way:

```
http://url.com/?slide1=7&slide2=6
```

So, change your accordingly :

```
<form action="yourBusinessPhpFile.php" method="GET">
    <!-- demo 1 -->
    <fieldset>

        <select name="slide1" id="num" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <optgroup label="low">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="mid">
            <option value="3" >3</option>
            <option value="4" selected="selected">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="high">
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
        </optgroup>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

To retrieve them in your PHP code (yourBusinessPhpFile.php), use the usual operators:

```
$var1 = $_GET["slide1"];
$var2 = $_GET["slide2"];
```

Regards

Comment: Wait, a problem, When I manually change the slider, the pulldown menu changes but the url doesn't change. The pulldown menu works perfectly.